# Separate ng-repeat for all ng-repeats..?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have this little problem. Im using ng-repeat for all my items, lets call them Countries, every item has an ng-repeat in itself as sub-categories like cities. I populate my dropdown menu with Countries.

so i have list of countries like this:

USA

GERMANY

SPAIN

ITALY

now this is 1 ng-repeat, now when i click on 1 country the following happens:

USA

GERMANY

- Stuttgart
- Berlin
- Koln
- Munchen

SPAIN

ITALY

so far so good, now when i open another country the following happens:

USA

GERMANY

- Stuttgart
- Berlin
- Koln
- Munchen

SPAIN

- Stuttgart
- Berlin
- Koln
- Munchen

ITALY

only one list can be active, 1 list of 1 country, how do i solve this? i want every country to be able to open their lists on click. anyone an idea? or at least could you give me some advice is this a common problem?

**EDIT:** **SOME CODE:**

```
<div class="category-body" ng-repeat="c in Country">
  <div class="category-main" ng-click="GetCities(c.Id);">
   <label class="pull-left">{{c.Name}}</label><input type="checkbox" class=" openSubCat" >
                </div>

 <div class="category-sub">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="L in Cities" >
      <label class=" pull-left">
                                                        {{L.Name}}
```

**AngularCode**

```
$scope.GetCountries= function() {
        $http.get('myURL')
            .then(Countries, ErrorResponse);
    }
 $scope.GetCities= function(id) {
        $http.get('myURL' + id)
            .then(Cities, ErrorResponse);
    }
```

**EDIT**
not my plnkr but this is the idea I want to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/NP7P5/

Comment: Show us some code besides the results they produce.

Comment: For real, this is "some" code, but nothing we can suggest. Please create a plunker.

Comment: @lin the code is not the problem its the logic.. how do i seperate the ng-repeats...

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. We need your hole view, data and controller. Its a specific problem.

Comment: for the Countries array put an extra filed that show which is active or not. In GetCities(c.Id) function set newly added field as an active and all others elements in Countries array inactive.

Comment: @lin ok.. give me some time to recreate it on plunker

Comment: We will solve your problem very quick. Thanks for the plunker!

Comment: @BharatBhushan yeah, but that gives me just 1 Country active, i want more then 1 country active, maybe put the cities in a scope?

Comment: @AlminIslamovic Mean you want to get all the cities which is under active country ?

Comment: @BharatBhushan yeah, i want USA - usacities, Germany - germancities to be active not just 1 country

Comment: create a new JSON Object like {"usa":[list of usa cities],"india":[list of india cities]}. So when country is active add cities in to this object with country name as key and when unselect remove it form this object.

Comment: This is something you should have researched on the web

Comment: Either share your code, or plunker. That will serve better

Comment: @BharatBhushan yeah, i figured i must do something like that :/ thanks

Comment: @AlminIslamovic  good job. mark my answer as accepted .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your selected countries city in a JSON object.

```
var selectedCities = {"usa:[list of usa cities],"india":[list of india cities]};
```

add or remove keys based on country is selected or not from selectedCities.

Comment: Just a question, how do i do that in my case, how do i put 2 json objects in 1? my example: 

`$http.get('myURL').
        then(CountryMenu, ErrorResponse);
}


var CountryMenu = function(response) {
        $scope.Countries= response.data;        
    }


$http.get('myURL').
        then(CitiesMenu, ErrorResponse);

var CitiesMenu = function(response) {
        $scope.Cities= response.data;        
    }`

var CombinedMenu = $scope.Menu = CountriesMenu + CitiesMenu?
how do i achieve this?

Comment: how you figure out which cities are from which country ? update GetCities(c.Id); with GetCities(c.Id,countryName); . when you get response add these cities with countryName key. its just logic not the problem